# How to sort a map[int]int by its values?

Tags: sorting, go, slice, quicksort

My insertion and quicksort does not work on map[uint64]uint64 values. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance. Would like to have sort of the map "aint" by value.

Please ask for details if any. I will improve on this question. Thanks again.

```
package main

import (
    "sort"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "runtime"
    "math/rand"
)
    func main() {

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    start := time.Now()

    //the map variable
    aint := map[uint64]uint64{}

    start = time.Now()
    for i := uint64(0); i < 100000000; i++ {
            aint[i+32132112313] = uint64(rand.Intn(13123123123)+2312423213) //random generation of input data
//              aint = insertSort(aint,uint64(rand.Intn(13123123123)))
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", aint[22] )

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("Entry took %s %d\n", elapsed)

    start = time.Now()
    quicksort(aint)

    //      sort.Sort(sort.IntSlice(aint))

    elapsed = time.Since(start)
    fmt.Printf("Sorting took %s %d\n", elapsed)
}
func insertionsort(items []int) {
    var n = len(items)
    for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
            j := i
            for j > 0 {
                    if items[j-1] > items[j] {
                            items[j-1], items[j] = items[j], items[j-1]
                    }
                    j = j - 1
            }
    }
}


func quicksort(a map[uint64]uint64) map[uint64]uint64 {
    if len(a) < 2 {
            return a
    }

    left, right := uint64(0), uint64(len(a)-1)

    pivot := Uint64() % uint64(len(a))

    a[pivot], a[right] = a[right], a[pivot]
    // does not work anymore from here onwards.
    for uint64(i), _ := range a {
            if a[i] < a[right] {
                    a[left], a[i] = a[i], a[left]
                    left++
            }
    }

    a[left], a[right] = a[right], a[left]

    quicksort(a[:left])
    quicksort(a[left+1:])

    return a
}
```

Comment: This will not even build. Please show a include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A golang map, which is just a hash table, is by definition unordered. There's no way you can sort the data it actually holds. At best, you can create a wrapper type comprised of the actual map, and a slice holding the keys, and sort the slice. When you iterate the map, then, you'd actually iterate the ordered slice and retrieve the data from the map in a set order. This is fairly trivial to implement, yet I can't help but feel like you're trying to solve an X-Y problem here. What are you trying to do? Maybe there's a better way

Answer (score 1):

Go maps are unordered data structures. No matter what you do it will not be sorted, either by key or by value.

If you want to sort your values, you should use a slice and perform your quicksort over that.

See the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) or [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps) for more details.